# Pandas itertuple returns inconsistent type, either Pandas or tuple

Tags: python, pandas, vcf-variant-call-format

I am getting a strange behavior that I have never seen before from my code that I have used many times before on smaller datasets. I am parsing VCF files with Pandas dataframe read_table. VCF files have a header and then 9 columns + however many columns of individuals. Before when I used `for row in genomes_df.itertuples():` to iterate through each row of the dataframe I could call a column, "SVLEN", with `row.SVLEN`. When I check `type(row)` it is a Pandas object. Today I ran my script on a larger file (350 columns vs 10 columns previously) of same VCF format, it is giving me `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'SVLEN'` because now `type(row)` is a tuple!

What is going on here? The column names are different (`NWD107911.mark_dupes` vs `NWD107911`)  but I checked that there are no spaces in the names (read in another post that it could cause different behavior).

Comment: Can you replicate this with a dummy dataframe e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])` ?

Comment: What version of pandas are  you using? Perhaps an older version did not use namedtuple?

Comment: `itertuples` should always return a tuple. Depending on your pandas version, it might not return a *named tuple* allowing you to access the values using an attribute name

Comment: @AndyHayden using the same script on a VCF of 10 and then 350 columns gives me the difference so I don't think it's a pandas version issue. I will try a dummy dataframe.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have pandas version 0.22

Comment: @AndyHayden I ran the test df and it returns a Pandas object. Maybe Pandas has a column limit and then has to use tuples?

Comment: I discovered after making a series of dummy dataframes that 253 columns is the limit before it converts the object to a tuple. I tested it with 10 rows. That is quite annoying as I didn't see that in the documentation.

Comment: @nchuang It is in the documentation actually, good find. You should answer this. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html "With a large number of columns (>255), regular tuples are returned."

Comment: @nchuang I answered, as the source code/python bug report is interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's mentioned in the [`iterttuples` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html):

> With a large number of columns (>255), regular tuples are returned.

and you can see in the source code [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/bd4332f4bff135d4119291f66e98f76cc5f9a80e/pandas/core/frame.py#L829-L839):

```
        # Python 3 supports at most 255 arguments to constructor, and
        # things get slow with this many fields in Python 2
        if name is not None and len(self.columns) + index < 256:
            # `rename` is unsupported in Python 2.6
            try:
                itertuple = collections.namedtuple(name,
                                                   fields + list(self.columns),
                                                   rename=True)
                return map(itertuple._make, zip(*arrays))
            except Exception:
                pass
```

Note: This restriction of 255 arguments to a cpython call/namedtuples has been [fixed in python 3.7](https://bugs.python.org/issue18896), so potentially this could be changed in future versions of pandas (running on python 3.7+).

Comment: I am using 3.7.3 and I still experience this issue